# Property file in Tomcat\bin folder getting java.util.MissingResourceException

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to read a properties file from `Tomcat\bin` folder using `ResourceBundle`.
When I put my properties file in project's root folder, I am able to read this file. 
But when I put it in `Tomcat\bin` folder, I'm getting `java.util.MissingResourceException`. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5):

You need to put it in the classpath. The `Tomcat/bin` folder is not part of the webapp's default runtime classpath. If you intend to add an external folder to the classpath of a webapp running in Tomcat, then you need to specify the path to that folder in the `shared.loader` property of the `Tomcat/conf/catalina.properties` file. I would however choose a different folder than the `Tomcat/bin`.

---

**Unrelated** to the problem, the `ResourceBundle` API is meant to read resourcebundle files (with localized content so that you can internationalize your app), not to read simple properties files (with configuration settings). For that you should be using [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) instead and not abuse the [`java.util.ResourceBundle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
// ...
```

Comment: do i need to give the complete path as "C:\Tomcat 6.0\bin"
in shared.loader or is there any way to give relative path

Comment: Open the `/conf/catalina.properties` file and read the comment above the property. It's well documented. It says among others that it can be relative to `CATALINA_BASE`. I would like to remind that it's a terribly bad idea to add `Tomcat/bin` to the classpath. Use a separate folder.

Comment: k,thanx a lot i'll keep  it in separate folder Tomcat\properties