# System.getProperty("catalina.base") There can be scenario where client may use any other server

Tags: java

I am reading a properties file from the `Tomcat\conf\somename.properties` directory using

```
String demo = System.getProperty("catalina.base") +
                  File.separator + "conf" + File.separator + "somename.properties";
```

This is working perfectly fine with Tomcat. But, there can be scenario where client may use any other server like Glassfish or Websphere, in that case I won't be able to get `System.getProperty("catalina.base")`.

How should I solve it properly? I'm able to do that using `ResourceBundle` but for that I have to keep my properties file in my build, which I don't want. I just want to read my properties file from outside my build.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are basically two ways.

1. Just add its path to the runtime classpath so that you can get it from the classpath the usual way. In case of Tomcat, you can add external folders to the runtime classpath by specifying it in the `shared.loader` property of `/conf/catalina.properties`. E.g.

   ```
   shared.loader = ${catalina.home}/conf
   ```

   Or better, don't be server-specific

   ```
   shared.loader = /path/to/folder
   ```

   Other servers also supports adding external folders to the classpath, consult their documentation.

   This way you'll be able to get an `InputStream` of it from the classpath as follows:

   ```
   InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
   Properties properties = new Properties();
   properties.load(input);
   // ...
   ```

   ---
2. Add another server-independent system property yourself, you can set as a VM argument.

   ```
   -Dconfig.location=/path/to/folder
   ```

   In case of Tomcat, you can set it as `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable, or edit the `catalina.bat` startup file or edit the Windows Service settings (when it's installed as Windows Service), etc. Other servers supports similar constructs as well.

   This way you can obtain it as follows

   ```
   File file = new File(System.getProperty("config.location"), "config.properties");
   InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
   Properties properties = new Properties();
   properties.load(input);
   // ...
   ```

   ---

Either way you choose, when distributing your application, you should **document it properly** so that the serveradmin can configure it accordingly.

---

**Unrelated** to the problem, the `ResourceBundle` is *not* the right way to read configuration properties files. It's intented for localized content for internationalization.

Comment: I discovered in your question history that you've already asked a similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082180/property-file-in-tomcat-bin-folder-getting-java-util-missingresourceexception How exactly was the answer unclear?

Comment: i was not able to set shared.loader = ${catalina.home}/conf
But thanx a ton for your this answer.......

Comment: I prefer Suraj's answer because it can work without any configuration, whereas here we must set the location in some environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, don't rely on `catalina.base`, that is your first problem :)

Or, more precisely, the java servlet api gives you access to resources inside your web application, so your app is truly portable (not only between servers, but also you can put it anywhere on the file system, zipped as a war or exploded)

Say you put your file at `<webapp-root>/WEB-INF/somename.properties`, then this is what you do in your servlet, listener, or other web-aware classes:

```
getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/somename.properties");
```

See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/howto-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive).

Another alternative is to use regular java api to search for files in your classpath, e.g. `this.getClass().getResource("/somename.properties")`. In the case of a web application, this will find such a file located under `/WEB-INF/class/` or any jar under `/WEB-INF/lib/`.

Finally, if you can't put the file inside your web application, you can put it anywhere on the hard drive and use some config param (e.g. a system property, or a context parameter in web.xml) to refer to it.

Comment: The thing is i cant place this file.Installer gonna place this property file for me.So there is no way to get that file in my build.
I just want to read it from outside my build

Comment: I just added that info while you were commenting. This is a typical use-case for a system parameter used with -D flag or something.

Answer (score 1):

First use the [ServletContext.getServerInfo()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServerInfo%28%29) to determine the container. Then based on the container, use container specific ways of getting the information. For e.g. if the method returns "tomcat*" then you can use catalina.base thing, if it returns glassfish, then use some glassfish specific ways, and so on.

Comment: we can do this thing using ResourceBundle as well. But not sure how to use that.I've used ResourceBundle but its not able to read file outside my build

Comment: That seems the best answer or else I misunderstood it.  The way I understand it, this is just the standard wrapper approach over different platforms, just as jquery does for javascript over different browsers.

Comment: Can you tell me what the GlassFish specific way is? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: don't think, this is right way of doing it; accepted answer makes sure that code is agnostic to app/web servers.